# Why is TypeScript OK with an arrow function returning more than an explicit void, but errors on a function doing the same?

Tags: typescript, void

I can't find an explanation for what happens in the following TypeScript snippet :

```
const f1: () => void = () => 4; // <- OK

function f2(): void {
  return 4; // <- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void'.
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRgFwwBQEoYF4B8MBuIAlgCbZqa4wAsA3DAPQMwA8AtDAPIDSAsAFAC4AVzDAoRcPABMGFIVIwA3gJgwATgFMow9WBr0mrDgBUAngAdNMAORhhAWwBGm9TZhEIMMCFgBDCAgiAHMwPycAG2soEBgoS2sbBRIbADoBAF8gA)

Why is TypeScript OK with an arrow function returning more than an explicit `void`, but complains on a declared function doing the same ?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Probably worth raising an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues. What version of Typescript?

Comment: You can see it happens even on the most recent of TypeScript in the playground, v.4.3.5

Comment: Posted an issue on the TypeScript repo : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45247